# Symfony2-Twig- Accessing stdclass object array

Tags: symfony, twig

may be someone can explain me what i am goting wrong.

I get response from riak bucket, which i prepare in action controller and render the response in twig.
But i can not iterate over the response with loop in twig.

When i do that in twig:

```
{%% for callback in callbacks %}
 {{ dump(callback) }}
 {% endfor %}
```

I get this:

```
Doc {#410 ▼   
  #data: {#422 ▼
    +"psStatus_i": 0
    +"psUrl_s": ""
    +"clickId_s": "1_3_4_f1a9bcf2faaa2ef67a39916ba06cbbb0"
    +"id_s": "565f04da60030fa3048b4572"   
  }   
#_yz_id:1*CallBackDataIn_all*all*1_3_4_f1a9bcf2faaa2ef67a39916ba06cbbb0*24"   
}
```

but when i want to get explicit one field like:

> {{ callback.id_s }}

i get then:

> Method "id_s" for object "Basho\Riak\Search\Doc" does not exist

I try to cast to array bvt then i get array to string exception.

Any idea, what i am doing wrong.

EDIT:
This is output with var_dump() in php:

```
object(Basho\Riak\Search\Doc)[410]   protected 'data' => 
    object(stdClass)[422]
      public 'psStatus_i' => int 0
      public 'psUrl_s' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'clickId_s' => string '1_3_4_f1a9bcf2faaa2ef67a39916ba06cbbb0' (length=38)
      public 'id_s' => string '565f04da60030fa3048b4572' (length=24)   
protected '_yz_id' => string                 '1*CallBackDataIn_all*all*1_3_4_f1a9bcf2faaa2ef67a39916ba06cbbb0*25' (length=66)   
protected '_yz_rk' => string '1_3_4_f1a9bcf2faaa2ef67a39916ba06cbbb0' (length=38)
```

Comment: try `{{ callback.data.id_s }}`

Comment: use {{ callback['id_s'] }}, the dot notation is assuming the use of getter functions on the object

Comment: @Matteo: tried already before posting....but the same exception:
Method "id_s" for object "Basho\Riak\Search\Doc" does not exist

Comment: try mixing the two comment `{{ callback.data['id_s'] }}`

Comment: @Rooneyl: is not possible, because not array:

Impossible to access a key "id_s" on an object of class "Basho\Riak\Search\Doc" that does not implement ArrayAccess interface

Comment: @Matteo: doesnt work:
Method "data" for object "Basho\Riak\Search\Doc" does not exist

Comment: try posting your Doc class

Comment: May be `attribute(callback, 'id_s')` will do the trick?

Comment: @Basil the same:
Method "id_s" for object "Basho\Riak\Search\Doc" does not exist

Comment: Where is the error from? Is it TwigException or PHP Fatal error?

Comment: Have you tried access the field outside the template in PHP code?

Comment: @Basil
Output is coming in Symfony with this info:
throw new Twig_Error_Runtime(sprintf('Method "%s" for object "%s" does not exist', $item, get_class($object)), -1, $this->getTemplateName());

However it works with php in indexAction() of Controller like below:

foreach ($callBacks as $callBack){
    $callBack->id_s;
            }
            
But when i then render the Twig-template and load $callBacks in to the template and make loop then i can not access the properties!

Comment: @Basil

here is the url to class:
https://github.com/basho/riak-php-client/blob/develop/src/Riak/Command/Search/Response.php

Comment: try `{{ callback.__get('id_s') }`

Comment: @Matteo you are great! This worked for me. 
This means magic __get() can pickup the property.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I see this method in the source code here https://github.com/basho/riak-php-client/blob/develop/src/Riak/Search/Doc.php#L67

Comment: can i post as an answer so you can close the question?

Comment: have you see this bundle https://github.com/remialvado/RiakBundle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In accordion with the [source code](https://github.com/basho/riak-php-client/blob/develop/src/Riak/Search/Doc.php#L67) of the class, you can access yo the value as follow:

```
{%% for callback in callbacks %}
    {{ callback.__get('id_s') }
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score -1):

@Matteo
Once again thx. But i am little bit confused because i ask myself why it works in php with $callBack->id_s without magic __get() and not in twig?

Another question, do you recommend remialvado? 
Basho is the official php_client for Riak.

Comment: I think that's because when twig try to acces foo.bar it check first whether the property bar is exist with `isset($foo->bar)` and it fails because there is no such a property and `__isset` method isn't defined in Doc class.